# How to override classpath in sbt build project?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using an sbt plugin that reads an embedded resource via

```
  new InputStreamReader(
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/%s" format src), utf8
  )
```

for example

```
  src = "resources/main.js"
```

I want to override this resource in the classpath that used by sbt build project itself, to make it using my "resources/main.js" instead of distributed with plugin.jar.

Comment: Where is `src` set? Is `src` an sbt setting? Is main.js a file you want to be packed into the assembly?

Comment: src is hardcoded path in sbt plugin. Inside private method, I can't change it. That is why I want to override the resource itself, if possible.

Comment: Alright. Please let us know a link to the source code of the plugin.

Comment: https://github.com/softprops/coffeescripted-sbt/blob/master/src/main/scala/compiler.scala#L48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me helped adding this to build.sbt:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Runtime <+= (baseDirectory) map { bd => Attributed.blank(bd / "resources") }
```

and I put overrided resources to ./resources directory. SBT checked them first.